# Help in identifying a book series where two boys and a girl journey through different worlds

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book of this series a long time ago. It wasn't the first in the series. There were three main characters I think. I don't remember the plot or the motive but the characters were going somewhere to defeat someone and it involved going through a number of worlds. The book was about their journey to one such world. I'm not really sure but I think two were boys and the third was a girl. I think one boy's name started with 'F'.

I don't know the book's name but I remember that for some reason the title reminded me of Harry Potter (I don't know why.)

There were also trolls in the book.

The characters could use some sort of magic or atleast one could. I remember one of them ignited a magical fire (I think they were in cave at the time) and the fire burned much brighter than expected. The reason as one of the characters told was that they were getting nearer to something (their destination maybe?) and therefore the magic was getting stronger.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Farry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone?

Comment: No,not Harry Potter

Comment: Did the title remind you of Harry Potter because it's similar to *XY And The AB*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the series.
Seems like I got confused.The series I was looking for is called Diadem by John Peel.
It was the series' name that reminded me of Harry Potter and not the individual book,I read.
Sorry if the misinformation caused any inconvenience.